# "this" in the return statement in a function .fn in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

why returning "this" in this function here:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
```

`this` is the "DOM element" ? If we want to use the content of the function, why not referencing `$(this)` to use the element we are targeting, instead of `this`?

Thanks

Comment: in this case - `this` - refers to jQuery object

Comment: `this` inside the plugin ***is*** a jQuery object, not a DOMElement, hence why the chaining works when returning this.

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md

Comment: I think you may have been confused by the fact that the author of that code has also used `var cssmenu = $(this)` - they could have equally just done `var cssmenu = this`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe ok great thanks James Thorpe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery methods (properties of `$.fn`) aren't like jQuery event handler callbacks. The value of `this` is the jQuery object itself, not a DOM element.

The `$.fn` object is the protoype object for jQuery instances, so when you make a jQuery object

```
var jq = $(something);
```

then call a jQuery method:

```
jq.whatever();
```

the natural `this` rules of JavaScript determine that `whatever()` will be invoked with the jQuery object as the value of `this`.